# Making a mouse cursor visible programmatically when no mouse is connected

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, user-interface

I am trying to build `a touchless interface using C#`. I use this interface to control other programs, or windows UI elements. In order to do that I mainly use user32.dll to perform mouse control actions.

When I try to use `the touchless interface`, and when no mouse is connected to the pc, I can still move the mouse cursor, but it is invisible.

I am aware that through the use of mouse keys options, the mouse cursor can be made visible. However, I much rather make it visible programmatically, in the code.

Can the cursor be made visible using `.Net`?

Comment: *when no mouse is connected to the pc, I can still move the mouse cursor, but it is invisible.* How can you move the cursor and how do you know it is moving if invisible?

Comment: The icons in the background are highlighted when the invisible cursor passes over them. I move the cursor through the mouse functions in user32.dll.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user32.dll.

```
internal static class WinCursors
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowCursor(bool bShow);


    internal static void ShowCursor()
    {
        while (ShowCursor(true) < 0)
        {
             ShowCursor(true);
        }
    }

    internal static void HideCursor()
    {
        while (ShowCursor(false) >= 0) 
        {
             ShowCursor(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, with the corrections. It does make the cursor disappear and re-appear on a computer that a mouse is already connected to. However, ShowCursor method does not make mouse cursor visible on a computer where no mouse is connected.

Comment: Yeah, but i dont get it, what is the point of it to show mouse, if you dont have any connected mouse or any simulated mouse/device? Somehow, you should be able to simulate the device and triger the mouse events. And touch interface has nothing to do with mouse interface.

Comment: The interface is touchless.

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about your own application form or would you like to interact with another application?

If it's your own I think this approach under Windows.Forms namespace would halp you:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.hide(v=vs.110).aspx

If not I'm afraid you can't, C# is not that good to do windows side stuffs and when talking about windows shell interface the best route is almost always going through user32.dll, like here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648396(v=vs.85).aspx

I personally don't like to import an alien DLL to C# managed system, it just doesn't sound good enough, I would go C/C++ for that, but iif it's too much complex, which I think so, a good option would be golang, which has a richer standard lib and it's easier to deal with than C/C++, but, of course, it depends on your needs.

Cheers

Comment: I use a transparent, click through wpf interface in my program. So my main concern is to interact with other programs, and-or windows elements. I could not make ShowCursor function of user32.dll work either.

Answer (score -2):

Will this (or some variant) make you a visible cursor?

```
this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
```